# How to display the power of 6 in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, prefix

I want to display 10'6, however when I try my code it return error

```
IF labres.full_blood_count_twcc IS NOT NULL THEN
            v_labres := v_labres || ' Total White Cell Count#: '||labres.full_blood_count_twcc|| power(10,6) '/L ';
END IF;
```

is there a way to display prefixes in postgresql?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: type 'power' does not exists

Answer (score 0):

I just return `10<sup>6</sup>` then it shows what i want